# Not able to include a library in makefile

Tags: makefile, linker

I am kind of new in the use of **make.**

I have a library written in C which is in the folder *folder1*
 Where these files are there is also a makefile which is the following:

```
PREFIX ?= /usr/local

CC = gcc
AR = ar

CFLAGS = -std=gnu99 -fPIC -Wall -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-function -I. -O4

APRILTAG_SRCS := $(shell ls *.c common/*.c)
APRILTAG_HEADERS := $(shell ls *.h common/*.h /usr/include/flycapture/*.h)
APRILTAG_OBJS := $(APRILTAG_SRCS:%.c=%.o)
TARGETS := libapriltag.a libapriltag.so

.PHONY: all
all: $(TARGETS)
    @$(MAKE) -C example all

.PHONY: install
install: libapriltag.so
    @chmod +x install.sh
    @./install.sh $(PREFIX)/lib libapriltag.so
    @./install.sh $(PREFIX)/include/apriltag $(APRILTAG_HEADERS)
    @sed 's:^prefix=$$:prefix=$(PREFIX):' < apriltag.pc.in > apriltag.pc
    @./install.sh $(PREFIX)/lib/pkgconfig apriltag.pc
    @rm apriltag.pc
    @ldconfig

libapriltag.a: $(APRILTAG_OBJS)
    @echo "   [$@]"
    @$(AR) -cq $@ $(APRILTAG_OBJS)

libapriltag.so: $(APRILTAG_OBJS)
    @echo "   [$@]"
    @$(CC) -fPIC -shared -o $@ $^

%.o: %.c
    @echo "   $@"
    @$(CC) -o $@ -c $< $(CFLAGS)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    @rm -rf *.o common/*.o $(TARGETS)
    @$(MAKE) -C example clean
```

Then, in the folder *example* I have some example which I can just run by giving the following command in the terminal:

```
./opencv_demo
```

or

```
./apriltag_demo
```

In this folder *example* I have another makefile which is the following:

```
CC = gcc
CXX = g++

CPPFLAGS = -I..
CFLAGS = -std=gnu99 -Wall -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-function -O4
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -O4
LDFLAGS = -Lusr/include/flycapture -lpthread -lm 
INC_DIR = /usr/include/flycapture

TARGETS := apriltag_demo opencv_demo

.PHONY: all
all: apriltag_demo opencv_demo

apriltag_demo: apriltag_demo.o ../libapriltag.a
    @echo "   [$@]"
    @$(CC) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)

opencv_demo: opencv_demo.o ../libapriltag.a /usr/include/flycapture/Error.h
    @echo "   [$@]"
    @$(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS) `pkg-config --libs opencv`

%.o: %.c
    @echo "   $@"
    @$(CC) -o $@ -c $< $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS)

%.o: %.cc
    @echo "   $@"
    @$(CXX) -o $@ -c $< $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    @rm -rf *.o $(TARGETS)
```

If I do *make* in the *folder1* I get the following error:

```
opencv_demo.o: In function `main':
opencv_demo.cc:(.text.startup+0x24e): undefined reference to `FlyCapture2::Error::Error()'
opencv_demo.cc:(.text.startup+0x2a7): undefined reference to `FlyCapture2::Error::~Error()'
opencv_demo.cc:(.text.startup+0x11a0): undefined reference to `FlyCapture2::Error::~Error()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [opencv_demo] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/fschiano/Repositories/apriltag2/example'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

If I am not wrong this error tells me that I did not include a library.

In the file *opencv_demo.cc* I did:

```
#include "flycapture/FlyCapture2.h"
#include "flycapture/Error.h"
using namespace FlyCapture2;
```

Headers which are in /usr/include/flycapture a folder which contains all the headers needed for what I need in the file *opencv_demo.cc*.

I don't know why it is not working, someone is able to help me?

I think I should write in the makefile where to search for the libraries but I don't know how.

I tried to write the following things in the makefile separately but they are not working :

```
LDFLAGS = -Lusr/include/flycapture -lpthread -lm 
INC_DIR = /usr/include/flycapture
DEPS = $(INC_DIR)/Error.h
```

Comment: Where's the library mentioned in your `LDFLAGS`? You just added the search path.

Comment: How is your make-question related to C or cmake?

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment. 
the library I need is inside /usr/include/flycapture the one specified in -lpthread and -lm were already there before my manipulations.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong tags. I will edit that.

Comment: You haven't given us enough information to reproduce this error, but It looks as if 1) the makefile in `folder1/` neglects to build the object files, then 2) it builds libraries out of object files which might not exist, then 3) it calls the makefile in `example/`, which 4) tries to link against those libraries, which may be incomplete. I would scold the person who wrote these makefiles, then rewrite them from the ground up.

Comment: At the end I 'solved' my problem by writing a CMakeLists.txt file. 



This is now the only solution that I found.